# How can I add an x509 certificates bundle (ca-bundle.crt) to NSS database (~./pki/nssdb)

Tags: git, openssl, certificates, github

I'm currently using RedHat Enterprise 6. Git had issues cloning Github repos using HTTPS. After some investigation (e.g. enabling GIT_CURL_VERBOSE and GIT_TRACE) the problem was narrowed to a certificate validation issue, which was solved updating the certificate DB, i.e.:

```
curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Things worked fine for a while. However, after a system upgrade now I'm getting a different error:

```
Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.30.252.128... * Connected to github.com (192.30.252.128) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* NSS error -5978
* Expire cleared
```

Unfortunately I can't find that error code description on [the documentation](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/sslerr.html).
It seems that the updated CURL system lib defaults to NSS and relies exclusively on the certificates on [/etc/pki/nssdb](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-compared.html)
I've been trying to solve this issue trying different commands to add the certificates to NSS, but failed.

**Can you recommend a solution? Is it possible to force Git and/or CURL to use the ca-bundle DB, or even disable certificate validation?**

*Any solution that could allow Git commands to be run using Github's repos wil be welcome.*

**Notes:**

*Curl version*
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can override the .crt file that `git` uses like this:

```
$ git config --system http.sslcainfo "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
```

You can disable SSL checks all together (not recommended):

```
$ git config --system http.sslverify false
```

Comment: Worked as expected, thank you (note: used sslverify=false in my user config file, not the system-wide )